# How to find minimum value in sorted dictionary with repeat elements?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys as items and values as their prices. I have to print the cheapest item.
if input is `dict_1={'mobile1':11000, 'mobile2':11000, 'mobile3':11000}`
then output - mobile1: 11000 in case of a tie in values, print whichever item came first should be the output.

and if input is `{'mobile1':10000, 'mobile2':9000, 'mobile3':13000}`
output is - `mobile2: 9000`.

My code is working for 2nd input set but failing for 1st input list where values are same.

```
dict_1={'mobile1':11000, 'mobile2':11000, 'mobile3':11000}
mobile=list(dict_1.keys())
price=list(dict_1.values())
for key,val in dict_1.items():
    if dict_1[key]==min(price):
        print('{0}: {1}'.format(key, val))
```

Expected output:

```
mobile1: 11000
```

actual result :

```
mobile1: 11000
mobile2: 11000
mobile3: 11000
```

Comment: Using numbered keys is usually considered bad practice. If you have a numbered sequence, use a list.

Comment: @KlausD.: The keys aren't numbers.

Comment: @martineau But they are **numbered**.

Comment: @KlausD. That's probably just for illustration purposes. The important point I think is that the keys are strings that are sorted.

Comment: Yah I accepted .Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `min()` function for this.

```
>>> dict_1={'mobile1':11000, 'mobile2':11000, 'mobile3':11000}
>>> min(dict_1, key=dict_1.get)
'mobile1'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dict_1 = {'mobile1':11000, 'mobile2':11000, 'mobile3':11000}
ans = sorted(dict_1.keys(), key = lambda x: dict_1[x])[0]
print(str(ans) + ': ' + str(dict_1[ans]))
```